# change content automatically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several images that should change manually and automatically. I used jquery with click function for this. the click function works. However, the images should change automatically.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('.tab-content:first').show();
  $('.tabs-nav .wp-block-button__link').click(function() {
    let currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $(currentTab).fadeIn();

    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
body, html, .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 20;
    right: 20
}
#content {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: max-content
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="wp-container-1 wp-block-buttons tabs-nav">
  <div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="#tab1">1</a></div>
  <div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="#tab2">2</a></div>
  <div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="#tab3">3</a></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  <img class="tab-content" id="tab1" style="display: none;height: 100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/fff/aaa" alt=""/> 
  <img class="tab-content" id="tab2" style="display: none;height: 100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/ccc/aaa" alt=""/> 
  <img class="tab-content" id="tab3" style="display: none;height: 100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/999/aaa" alt=""/> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) to call a function every N seconds which changes the image - effectively the same logic as in your click handler. You just need to know which image is currently shown in order to move to the next one.

Comment: "*automatically*" can have various meanings, eg which the user points (mouseover) rather than click, when something in the database or elsewhere on the page changes, every n seconds (which, tbf is the most likely).  Please be clear.

Comment: Determining the current one can be done use `:visible` (https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) or, perhaps easier, by adding/removing a class such as "active" when you hide/fadeIn.

Comment: The question is ambiguous and requires more detail. It appears that you are trying to create an image carousel using a WordPress tab widget.

Comment: no, this is not implemented in wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('.tab-content:first').show();
  $('.tabs-nav .wp-block-button__link').click(function() {
       let currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
       var val = parseInt(currentTab.substr(4))
       test(val);    
  });
});
function test(val)
{ 
   $('.tab-content').hide();
   $("#tab"+val).fadeIn();
   setTimeout(function() {
    val +=1;
    if(val < 4)
    {
      test(val);
    }else{
      test(1);
    }
   },5000);
}
```

```css
body, html, .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 20;
    right: 20
}
#content {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: max-content
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="wp-container-1 wp-block-buttons tabs-nav">
  <div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="#tab1">1</a></div>
  <div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="#tab2">2</a></div>
  <div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="#tab3">3</a></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  <img class="tab-content" id="tab1" style="display: none;height: 100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/fff/aaa" alt=""/> 
  <img class="tab-content" id="tab2" style="display: none;height: 100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/ccc/aaa" alt=""/> 
  <img class="tab-content" id="tab3" style="display: none;height: 100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/999/aaa" alt=""/> </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('.tab-content:first').show();
  $('.tabs-nav .wp-block-button__link').click(function() {
    let currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $(currentTab).fadeIn();

    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
body, html, .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 20;
    right: 20
}
#content {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: max-content
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="wp-container-1 wp-block-buttons tabs-nav">
  <div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="#tab1">1</a></div>
  <div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="#tab2">2</a></div>
  <div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="#tab3">3</a></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  <img class="tab-content" id="tab1" style="display: none;height: 100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/fff/aaa" alt=""/> 
  <img class="tab-content" id="tab2" style="display: none;height: 100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/ccc/aaa" alt=""/> 
  <img class="tab-content" id="tab3" style="display: none;height: 100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/999/aaa" alt=""/> </div>
</div>
```

This should work though there is a dependency on name of id and number of div